# JAVA For loop tableview

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, javafx

This piece of code has to give me all the persons in the List but because the `TaSpelers.setItems` is in the for loop it only gives me the latest record he found. How do I fix it that my tableview is filled with all the items?

```
ArrayList < PersoonBag > perLijst = pdb.zoekSpelersPerPloeg(idPloeg);
for (PersoonBag r: perLijst) {
    PersoonBag persoon = new PersoonBag(r.getId(), r.getNaam(), r.getVoornaam(), r.getMyDate(), r.getOpmerking(), r.isIsTrainer(), r.getPloeg());


    ObservableList < PersoonBag > spelerLijst = FXCollections.observableArrayList(persoon);

    spelerLijst.sorted();
    System.out.println(spelerLijst);
    taSpelers.setItems(spelerLijst);
}
```

**Note:** putting it ouside my for loop i can't acces my variables **

Comment: (a) Indent your code properly. (b) Show all the variable definitions.

Comment: i added my one and only needed variable ..

Comment: (c) show the close of the loop body so we can tell what is in the loop and what is outside it

Comment: actually the last line is the close of the loop

Comment: the if statement is not the cause, i might aswell delete it.

Comment: System.out.println(spelerLijst) gives me the amount of records but the problem is that everytime i do the for loop it only adds one but forgets the other record

Comment: Create the (empty) list before the loop, `add(...)` the elements to the list in the loop, and call `setItems(...)` after the loop.

Comment: Do you really need to create copies of all the individual elements, by the way? If not, you can just do `taSpelers.getItems().setAll(perLijst);` and get rid of the loop entirely.

Comment: @James_D, I don't know who you are but It worked! Thank you so much and next questions I'll make them a lot clearer! Thank you, I admire you!

Comment: An `ObservableList` is still just an implementation of the `java.util.List` interface. You can use an observable list in exactly the same way you use a regular `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks James D!

answer:

Create the (empty) list before the loop, add(...) the elements to the list in the loop, and call setItems(...) after the loop

Answer (score 0):

We can't see what type of object taSpelers is because you didn't include its declaration but I would guess that you want to use a method like "addItems" instead of "setItems".

Comment: `spelerLijst` is declared inside the loop... it's an `ObservableList<PersoonBag>`.